# In official Pathfinder lore, are there any examples of magic users capable of overwriting rules of magic spells completely?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, spellcasting

Are there any magic users that are capable of overwriting magical laws to a degree that would be required to remove any limitations and completely perfect existing spells?

To be clear, I’m looking for a specific example of a caster in *Pathfinder* lore. Can be an NPC, divine, even a plain old human, anything goes as long as it’s from official lore.

For example, *stone shield* requires a large amount of earth, so it can’t be used on say a frozen lake. *Ice spear* melts and thus can’t be used as a permanent barrier save places like the arctic and wouldn’t last very long in hot areas such as the desert. *Astral projection* has the silver thread. There are very few ways to get around energy resistance short of changing the element.  Even something like ignoring components or casting spells instantly would be a major improvement.

Can such a mage exist that is capable of making spells work perfectly with no weaknesses?

Comment: I don't know what's meant by being able to "remove any drawbacks and completely perfect existing spells." Could the question detail this further?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I added examples. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 5):

> Even something like ignoring components (...) would be a major improvement.

Razmir from [The Inner Sea World Guide](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/The_Inner_Sea_World_Guide) created his arcane Razmiran Priests, base class version (found underaanother name [in OGL Content](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo-sorcerer-archetypes/razmiran-priest/) due to copyright). These arcane casters can ignore even the costly material components if they are using a *divine* focus, and cast spells from items (like scrolls) without using up any charges or destroying the item. In the lore, such changes were made possible by the Razmir himself.